# How do you guarantee fairness with async join?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

With my Rust server, I have dozens, possibly 1000s of async connections. They all are responsive and many will be ready on any given poll.

I'd like to guarantee that there is fairness, and a few of the first don't get priority. Essentially, I'd like to advance all of the ready before performing another poll loop.

Do I need to roll my own `join!` or should I use some other scheduling/polling mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `FuturesUnordered` is how I can accomplish my goal.

Comment: Could you expand that a bit, to flesh it out as an answer?

Comment: I'm still working through a solution. I need to wait on the accept and wait on each new stream. I also want to limit concurrent connections, which impacts accept waiting.

Comment: In the end I abandoned `FuturesUnordered`, as I found that spawning a task to handle the stream proved the most fair, this provided both concurrent and parallel (with a threaded executor) execution.